# Saving UIColor to and loading from NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults, uicolor

What's the easiest way to save a `UIColor` into `NSUserDefaults` and then get it back out?

Comment: Saving UIColor as raw binary data without NSKeyedArchiver//NSKeyedUnarchiver (NSCoding)  https://stackoverflow.com/a/34366333/2303865

Answer (score 78, accepted):

With [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1275790/2546659), you'll quickly end up with a lot of NSKeyed archives & unarchives all over your code. A cleaner solution is to extend UserDefaults. This is exactly what extensions are for; UserDefaults probably doesn't know about UIColor as it is because UIKit and Foundation are different frameworks.

#### Swift

```
extension UserDefaults {

    func color(forKey key: String) -> UIColor? {
        var color: UIColor?
        if let colorData = data(forKey: key) {
            color = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: colorData) as? UIColor
        }
        return color
    }

    func set(_ value: UIColor?, forKey key: String) {
        var colorData: Data?
        if let color = value {
            colorData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: color)
        }
        set(colorData, forKey: key)
    }

}
```

### Swift 4.2

```
extension UserDefaults {

    func color(forKey key: String) -> UIColor? {

        guard let colorData = data(forKey: key) else { return nil }

        do {
            return try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: UIColor.self, from: colorData)
        } catch let error {
            print("color error \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return nil
        }

    }

    func set(_ value: UIColor?, forKey key: String) {

        guard let color = value else { return }
        do {
            let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: color, requiringSecureCoding: false)
            set(data, forKey: key)
        } catch let error {
            print("error color key data not saved \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

    }

}
```

#### Usage

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(UIColor.white, forKey: "white")
let whiteColor = UserDefaults.standard.color(forKey: "white")
```

This can also be done in Objective-C with a category.

I've added the Swift file as a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/eaa3ef99e211bee76a58).

Comment: You can do this in Objective-C with a category, also.

Answer (score 134):

One way of doing it might be to archive it (like with NSColor, though I haven't tested this):

```
NSData *colorData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:color];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:colorData forKey:@"myColor"];
```

And to get it back:

```
NSData *colorData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myColor"];
UIColor *color = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:colorData];
```

Comment: UIColor implements the NSCoding protocol, so archiving will work.

Comment: This method serializes a color to 315 bytes of data .. seems like a bit of a waste.  Erica Sadun's UIColor category referenced by lifjoy's answer seems like a better solution.

Comment: This way also saves the color profile associated with the color. If that's not important to you, sure.

Comment: @Wevah This doesn't seem to work with CCColor, do you have any ideas for that?

Comment: @Jason Do you mean CGColor?

Comment: @Wevah I've tried both CGColor and CCColor, when trying to save to NSUserDefaults, the app crashes. Basically im trying to allow users to change the color of a sprite with 3 sliders and save that to load the sprite color across the app. _mySprite.color and _mySprite.color.CGColor, tried both and crashes with this error: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CCColor encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x155c9310'

Comment: @Jason I don't actually know what `CCColor` is…oh, it's Cocos2d stuff. Also, `CGColor` is a Core Foundation object, so it's not too surprising that the method doesn't work. IIRC you can turn a `CGColor` into a `UIColor` with `+[UIColor colorWithCGColor:]`, though.

Comment: @Wevah Thank you for your help! It looks like this would be a singleton? +[UIColor colorWithCGColor:] With your code above for the answer, how would I incorporate your code? Sorry still a newbie.

Comment: @Wevah Here is how I'm trying to save the color of the sprite and it's crashing:

`NSData *colorData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:_mySprite.color];
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:colorData forKey:@"spriteColor"];`

Comment: In Swift: `var colorData:NSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(color);
        defaults.setObject(colorData, forKey: "BackgroundColor");`

Comment: See my answer for a modern improvement to this one :)

Answer (score 7):

I've got the answer by myself

Save

```
const CGFloat  *components = CGColorGetComponents(pColor.CGColor);
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setFloat:components[0]  forKey:@"cr"];
[prefs setFloat:components[1]  forKey:@"cg"];
[prefs setFloat:components[2]  forKey:@"cb"];
[prefs setFloat:components[3]  forKey:@"ca"];
```

Load

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
UIColor* tColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:[prefs floatForKey:@"cr"] green:[prefs floatForKey:@"cg"] blue:[prefs floatForKey:@"cb"] alpha:[prefs floatForKey:@"ca"]];
```

Comment: The only issue that could arise is if the underlying CGColor isn't in the RGB colorspace. If you're certain it will be RGB, this is probably a nicer option than archival.

Comment: Aside from the RGB assumption, this solution will get annoying once you have two or more colors to preserve. Ideally, you want to store all the color information under a single key, not four, then write a generic get/set function.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for [Erica's UIColor category](http://arstechnica.com/apple/guides/2009/02/iphone-development-accessing-uicolor-components.ars).  I did not really like saving 4 floats in the preferences, and just wanted a single entry.

So using Erica's `UIColor` category, I was able to convert the **RGB** color to/from an `NSString` which can be saved in the preferences.

```
// Save a color
NSString *theColorStr = [self.artistColor stringFromColor];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:theColorStr forKey:@"myColor"];

// Read a color
NSString *theColorStr = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myColor"];
if ([theColorStr length] > 0) {
    self.myColor = [UIColor colorWithString:theColorStr];
} else {
    self.myColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:88.0/255.0 green:151.0/255.0 blue:237.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
}
```

Comment: Look into `[NSUserDefaults registerDefaults:]` to set a default value (so you can avoid the if/else when you read the value).

Comment: UIColor-Expanded.m and UIColor-Expanded.h files can be found here : https://github.com/ars/uicolor-utilities

Answer (score 3):

## Swift 3, `UserDefaults` Extension

```
extension UserDefaults {

    internal func color(forKey key: String) -> UIColor? {
        guard let colorData = data(forKey: key) else {
            return nil
        }

        return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: colorData) as? UIColor
    }

    internal func setColor(_ color: UIColor?, forKey key: String) {
        let colorData: Data?
        if let color = color {
            colorData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: color)
        }
        else {
            colorData = nil
        }

        set(colorData, forKey: key)
    }
}
```

### Example Use

```
let colorKey = "favoriteColor"

UserDefaults.standard.setColor(UIColor.red, forKey: colorKey)
let favoriteColor = UserDefaults.standard.color(forKey: colorKey)

print("favoriteColor is red: '\(favoriteColor == UIColor.red)'")
```

This answer is based on [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30576832/2092663). It is updated for Swift 3.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to store array of `UIColor` objects in User Defaults. Idea, as stated in other answers, is to convert `UIColor` to Data and save that data. I've made extension on `UIColor`:

```
extension UIColor {
   func data() -> Data {
      return NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self)
   }
   class func color(withData data: Data) -> UIColor? {
      return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? UIColor
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
fileprivate var savedColors: [UIColor]? {
    get {
        if let colorDataArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: Constants.savedColorsKey) as? [Data] {
            return colorDataArray.map { UIColor.color(withData: $0)! }
        }
        return nil
    }
    set {
        if let colorDataArray = newValue?.map({ $0.data() }) {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(colorDataArray, forKey: Constants.savedColorsKey)
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Swift

```
private let colorPickerKey = "ColorPickerKey"

var selectedColor: UIColor? {
    get {
        guard let colorData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: colorPickerKey) as? Data,
            let color = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: colorData) as? UIColor else { return nil }
        return color
    } set {
        guard let newValue = newValue else {
            UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: colorPickerKey)
            return
        }
        let colorData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: newValue)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(colorData, forKey: colorPickerKey)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

**Edit 2:** I seem to have found the [answer](http://arstechnica.com/apple/guides/2009/02/iphone-development-accessing-uicolor-components.ars).  Check out the article by Erica Sadun on extending UIColor.

**Edit:** This code does not seem to work for a UIColor Object. Not sure why...

Here is some code to take a look at:

Saving an object into NSUserDefaults:

```
 NSUserDefaults *userDefaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setObject:someColorObject forKey:@"myColor"];
```

Reading an object from NSUserDefaults:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
UIColor *someColor = (UIColor *)[userDefaults objectForKey:@"myColor"];
```

Comment: I appreicate for your help, but it seems that NSUserDefaults can't save UIColor object

Comment: hmm let me try the code i posted above - i just wrote it from memory.

Comment: check out the article i linked to in the post body

Comment: This doesn't work because NSUserDefaults can only store Property List Objects: NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSData, NSArray, and NSDictionary (where all keys must be strings). Anything else must be encoded as one of those objects.