# How to Input UIColor to User defaults?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsuserdefaults, uicolor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Saving UIColor to and loading from NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275662/saving-uicolor-to-and-loading-from-nsuserdefaults)

I think to init user defaults, make NSDictionary, input data, and refisterDefaults.
But this code has error.

```
//if UserFilter entry is nothing, create.
NSDictionary *defaultFilter = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:@"UserFilter"];
[userDefaults registerDefaults:defaultFilter];

//if UserBadgeColor entry is nothing, create.
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1];
NSValue *valColor = [NSValue value:&color withObjCType:@encode(UIColor)];
NSDictionary *defaultBadgeColor = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:valColor forKey:@"UserBadgeColor"];
[userDefaults registerDefaults:defaultBadgeColor];
```

Running, UserFilter part has no problem. But UserBadgeFilter part has error.
Error line is last.

Thanks.

Comment: Last line has "EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)

Comment: An object must be an instance of (or for collections a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. Note that `NSValue` is not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the manual:

> The NSUserDefaults class provides convenience methods for accessing common types such as floats, doubles, integers, Booleans, and URLs. A default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or for collections a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. If you want to store any other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an instance of NSData.

But you can simply use NSData, so in your case:

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1];
NSData* colorData= [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: color];
NSDictionary *defaultBadgeColor = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: colorData forKey:@"UserBadgeColor"];
[userDefaults registerDefaults:defaultBadgeColor];
```

And when you read from the defaults, decode back the data to UIColor using [NSKeyedUnarchiver](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedUnarchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html).