# How to save textview font, size, color and alignment by NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, uitextview, nsuserdefaults, uifont

How to allow app users to set font, size, color and alignment an application by custom setting? I am wondering if I can save an UIFont  to the NSUserDefaults. How can I get around this issue?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275662/saving-uicolor-to-and-loading-from-nsuserdefaults) for `UIColor`. For the `UIFont` now (since it doesn't adopt the `NSCoding` protocol, you could just keep a string with the font name or a dictionary with the required parameters and pass them to a method that would return a `UIFont` based on those upon retrieval from the defaults.

Comment: Have you looked into http://www.cocoacontrols.com There are ton of sample projects that let users choose font colors and change font text or sizes

Comment: Yes. Have a exellent example https://github.com/chrismiles/CMTextStylePicker    , but i need to save by NSUserDefaults

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `NSDictionary` holding:

> Font?

Its PostScript name.

> Size?

`NSNumber`

> Color?

`NSData` (see below)

> Alignment?

`NSNumber`

---

`NSUserDefaults` can save `NSData`. To serialize:

```
NSData * data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:color];
[[NSUserDefaults sharedUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:MONDefaultsKey];
```

then use `NSKeyedUnarchiver` to deserialize the `NSData` representation.

You might also consider saving it as a serialized `NSAttributedString` if there are associated string(s) -- but that is `NSUserDefaults` abuse in most cases.