# UIColor in NSUserDefaults Swift / iOS 8

Tags: swift, ios8, nsuserdefaults

I'm writing a Swift app for iOS. I need to set and later retrieve a UIColor object to NSUserDefaults.

I set it like this:

```
var userSelectedColor : NSData? = (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("UserSelectedColor") as? NSData)

if (userSelectedColor == nil) {
    var colorToSetAsDefault : UIColor = UIColor.redColor()
    var data : NSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(colorToSetAsDefault)
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(data, forKey: "UserSelectedColor")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    println("SET DEFAULT USER COLOR TO RED")
}
```

But I can't seem to get it back because the unarchive method on NSKeyedArchiver seems to be missing in Swift.

```
var userSelectedColorData: NSData? = (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("UserSelectedColor") as NSData)
var userSelectedColor : UIColor? = NSKeyedArchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(userSelectedColorData)
```

What is the proper way to do this in Swift / iOS 8?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unarchiving is done with `NSKeyedUnarchiver`, not with `NSKeyedArchiver`. You also should
use conditional casts (`as?`) to ensure that the application does not crash if the
saved user default is not of the expected type:

```
if let userSelectedColorData  = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("UserSelectedColor") as? NSData {
    if let userSelectedColor = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(userSelectedColorData) as? UIColor {
        println(userSelectedColor)
    }
}
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30576832/3681880) for doing this with extensions.