# Store UIColor in CoreData

Tags: swift, core-data, nsdata, uicolor, transformable

How can i store **UIColor in CoreData** without loss on **64 bit**? 
On 32 bit the correct UIColor is returned.

**CoreData setup**

- attribute type: **Transformable**
- NSManagedObject subclass property: **@NSManaged var color: UIColor?**

**Before the color value is stored**

```
color.getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha)
```

output e.g. red on 64bit:

```
0.20000000000000018
```

output red on 32 bit

```
0.199999928
```

**After the color is retrieved from CoreData**

```
color.getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha)
```

output e.g. red on 64bit:

```
0.20000000298023224
```

output red on 32 bit:

```
0.199999928
```

**Resulting Problem**

Color comparison, using == , fails on 64 bit, because the values slightly differ. On 32 bit everything is fine and color comparison succeeds.

Comment: Neither 32-bit nor 64-bit floats can store the number `0.2` exactly. Comparing floating point numbers with `==` is bad in most cases.

Comment: Have tried saving the colour values in Hex instead to avoid the precision issue altogether.

Comment: How are you archiving the UIColor? doing == with float / double is never a clever idea! Look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275662/saving-uicolor-to-and-loading-from-nsuserdefaults

Answer (score 3):

Assign `NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(color)` to a data variable and save that to your Core Data store instead.

To read the data, just assign `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(colorData)` to a color variable.

---

In case you're wondering how to compare floats anyways, you can always refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334688/how-dangerous-is-it-to-compare-floating-point-values).

Comment: I think the Core Data runtime does these transformations automatically if the attribute is defined as "Transformable". – And I am not sure if this solves the 32-bit vs 64-bit floating point issues that the question is about.

Comment: You shouldn't be comparing floats directly anyways. 64-bit has higher precision but is rounded when saved to the datastore, leaving a different value when taking out. Use epsilon :)

Comment: i do compare UIColor objects with color == colorRetrievedFromCoreData . The rounding CoreData seems to be the problem. This can be circumvented, as you suggested, by storing it as NSData, containing the encoded form of the UIColor object.

Comment: People will need this if they want to send UIColor to watch using context. Making the coreData attribute transformable is the other option to store UIColor but you won't be able to transfer it without converting to NSData. Just FYI

Answer (score 1):

**This solved my problem:**

1. set CoreData attribute name to my custom NSValueTransformer subclass: MQColorTransformer
2. implemented the following NSValueTransformer subclass (which is also converting UIColor to NSData, like **Schemetrical** suggested, but it has the advantage that i can still assign UIColor to my color property and NSValueTransformer takes care of the transformation behind the scence):

**NSValueTransformer subclass**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

@objc(MQColorTransformer) class MQColorTransformer: NSValueTransformer {

  override class func transformedValueClass() -> AnyClass{
      return NSData.classForCoder()
  }

  override func transformedValue(value: AnyObject!) -> AnyObject {

      // Transform UIColor to NSData
      let color = value as! UIColor

      var red: CGFloat = 0
      var green: CGFloat = 0
      var blue: CGFloat = 0
      var alpha: CGFloat = 0
      color.getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha)

      var components:[CGFloat] = [red, green, blue, alpha]
      let dataFromColors = NSData(bytes: components,
          length: sizeofValue(components)*components.count)

      return dataFromColors

  }

  override func reverseTransformedValue(value: AnyObject!) -> AnyObject {

      // Transform NSData to UIColor
      let data = value  as! NSData
      var components = [CGFloat](count: 4, repeatedValue:0)
      var length=sizeofValue(components)

      data.getBytes(&components, length: length * components.count)
      let color = UIColor(red: components[0],
          green: components[1],
          blue: components[2],
          alpha: components[3])

      return color
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that (unless I am mistaken) this representation is not device independent. If the color is archived on a 32-bit device and retrieved on a 64-bit device (or vice versa) the result will be wrong.

Comment: You realise that for the first function, you can `return NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(color)` and get rid of the rest of the code. For the second function, you can `return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data)` and get rid of the rest of the code. Its a far more elegant solution instead of retrieving color components.

Comment: @Schemetrical : This does not work, because comparison fails again on 64 bit.

Comment: You should not be comparing floats directly and rely on equally typed values to compare, use FLT_EPSILON :)

Comment: @Schemetrical: so you mean to check if the distance between two colors is e.g. less than FLT_EPSILON ?

Comment: @mc_plectrum indeed. Its the safest way and it isn't dependent on 64 or 32 bit devices. This is also the reason why many developers had issues migrating to a 64 bit environment. Its common practice to always compare floats with epsilon.

Answer (score 0):

### Swift 5.7, minimum deployment target iOS 11

```swift
import UIKit

final class ColorAttributeTransformer: ValueTransformer {
    override class func transformedValueClass() -> AnyClass {
        NSData.self
    }
    
    override func transformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
        let color = value as! UIColor
        
        return NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: color)
    }
    
    override func reverseTransformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
        let data = value as! Data

        return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data)
    }
}
```

Be aware, that Xcode complines in console:
`'NSKeyedUnarchiveFromData' should not be used to for un-archiving and will be removed in a future release`.