# How to type a color into a plist that I create not programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I know how to do this programmatically using this answer :
[Saving UIColor to and loading from NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275662/saving-uicolor-to-and-loading-from-nsuserdefaults)

But what are my options when I want to be able to pre load a `plist` I create in the editor ( creating a `plist` file and filling its fields - not by coding)  ? `Xcode` will give you only a few drop down menu options such as `string` `dictionary` `array` or `number`.

Is there a way to do it in the editor?   **I can create 3 fields for r/g/b and set then with numbers but it seems like a bad design**

Comment: You can add hex color code in plist, which you can read programmatically and can process.

Comment: why not a static class/properties with your colours?

Comment: @AnandSuthar Thats a good idea! can you elaborate on an answer ? The hex should be a string or a number ?

Comment: @LucasPalaian I used to put it on a singleton but it is a mess, I have some structure that I want to keep. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps are

1. Create a .plist array of dictionary as below image
   [image]
2. Read .plist values

   ```
   var myDict: NSDictionary?
   if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("colors", ofType: "plist") {
   myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
   }
   if let dict = myDict {
    // Use your dict here
   }
   ```
3. Once you get hex color then you can convert it to UIColor : [Hex-to-UIColor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24263007/how-to-use-hex-colour-values-in-swift-ios)

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to abstract that information from your code and it is not good enough for you to use some static constant, you can try an NSColor extension to parse string values and store thos values on plist.

Something like this worked for me:

```
import AppKit

extension NSColor {
    convenience init(hex:String) {

        var cString:String = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()

        if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
            cString = cString.substring(from: cString.characters.index(cString.startIndex, offsetBy: 1))
        }

        if ((cString.characters.count) != 6) {
            self.init (red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1.0)
        } else {

            var rgbValue:UInt32 = 0
            Scanner(string: cString).scanHexInt32(&rgbValue)

            self.init(red:CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0, green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0, blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0, alpha: CGFloat(1.0))
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing your colours in a plist, consider placing them in a struct: 'UIColor+Styling.swift'

```
public extension UIColor {
    struct AppName {
        static let white = UIColor(hex: "#FFFFFF")
        static let black = UIColor(hex: "#3D2C2A")
        static let red = UIColor(hex: "#D84C3A")
        static let darkRed = UIColor(hex: "#B84132")
        static let green = UIColor(hex: "#6C9491")
    }
}
```

Then you will be able to use them like this:

```
backgroundColor = UIColor.AppName.green
```

To initiate an UIColor object with a hex code implement this extension: 'UIColor+Hex.swift'

```
public extension UIColor {

    /// You can pass a hex with or without # and with or without alpha
    convenience init(hex: String) {
        var red: CGFloat = 0.0
        var green: CGFloat = 0.0
        var blue: CGFloat = 0.0
        var alpha: CGFloat = 1.0

        let cleanHex = hex.replacingOccurrences(of: "#", with: "")

        let scanner = Scanner(string: cleanHex)
        var hexValue: CUnsignedLongLong = 0
        if scanner.scanHexInt64(&hexValue) {
            if cleanHex.characters.count == 6 {
                red   = CGFloat((hexValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0
                green = CGFloat((hexValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8)  / 255.0
                blue  = CGFloat(hexValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0
            } else if cleanHex.characters.count == 8 {
                alpha   = CGFloat((hexValue & 0xFF000000) >> 24) / 255.0
                red = CGFloat((hexValue & 0x00FF0000) >> 16) / 255.0
                green  = CGFloat((hexValue & 0x0000FF00) >> 8)  / 255.0
                blue = CGFloat(hexValue & 0x000000FF)         / 255.0
            } else {
                print("invalid rgb string, length should be 6 or 8", terminator: "")
            }
        } else {
            print("scan hex error")
        }

        self.init(red:red, green:green, blue:blue, alpha:alpha)
    }
}
```